# How to merge method and description columns

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I'm new to javadoc. I've tried to generate javadoc with [Maven plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html). It works well, however, it generates 2 columns `Method` and `Description` instead 1 column `Method and Description`. I can't find option to merge these 2 columns.

Here is the config in the pom file:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

And, here is the result:

[image: The result]

What I would expect:

[image: My expect]

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Maven Javadoc plugin generates Javadoc with two columns: Method and Description. However, if you want to merge these two columns into a single column, you can use the `<noindex>true</noindex>` configuration option.

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <additionalparam>-noindex</additionalparam>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

By adding the `<additionalparam>-noindex</additionalparam>` configuration, you are passing the -noindex option to the Javadoc tool, which will result in a single column layout for the Method and Description.

After making this change, you can regenerate the Javadoc by running the Maven command mvn javadoc:javadoc. The generated Javadoc should now have a single column for Method and Description.

Comment: I've tried to add both `<noindex>true</noindex>` and `<additionalparam>-noindex</additionalparam>` into the configuration but still get the same result.